# LyX->Rnw conversion automatically inserts ligature breaks between repeated "<" characters

Tags: knitr, lyx

The title says it all; the screenshot below gives the gory details. (The .Rnw file in the temporary buffer folder is identical to the LaTeX Source in the image.) As you can imagine, `knit()` won't knit *this* crap. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make those ligature breaks go away.

So I guess my question is... Help?

[image]

Comment: I suppose I could add a mangled pattern to `knitr`, but I feel that two wrongs don't make a right, even if they would make the right TeX output. This thing is supposed to work straight out of the box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably did not read [the manual](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/lyx/), which has instructions on how to input R code in a LyX document: either through `Insert --> TeX Code` (`Ctrl + L`), or use the `Chunk` environment from the drop-down menu on the toolbar. You should not type R code as normal paragraphs in LyX.

Comment: That's correct, more-or-less. I did read something like that document four years ago during my first attempt at literate programming. (Explicit solution: use a TeX box (preferred) or a Chunk environment.)