# on my system, knitr can't compile a doc that uses the gdata package

Tags: knitr, lyx

My [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094607/knitr-lyx-missing-the-knitr-latex-converter-rscript-is-in-path-i-swear) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098969/lyx-rnw-conversion-automatically-inserts-ligature-breaks-between-repeated-c) questions were just embarrassing, but I feel confident that this one is the real deal. My system is a new install, so versions are current except for OS: Windows 7 SP1, R-3.0.1, Lyx 2.0.6, knitr 1.2, gdata 2.12.0.2.

First, let me note that gdata works correctly in RGui. Now, here's the doc I'm trying to compile:

[image]

And here's the output.

[image]

The gdata package also loads successfully in Rscript called from the command line. I used LyX to export an .Rnw file, which knits successfully from RGui and from a script passed to Rscript from the command line.

I had a similar (or possibly the same, I cannot swear to the identity of the error message) difficulty when I first started using the computer. That time it was due to Windows 7 User Account Controls, and was solved when I figured out how to automatically run R as an administrator (with no click-through -- sweet). So I tried removing the read-only attribute and all security restrictions on anything that might be involved -- the R folder, LyX folder, my package folder, MikTeX. No luck.

What next?

---

ETA: As near as I can tell, no R script called from LyX can load the gdata package. I altered the file converter to write stdout and stderr to file, which yielded the same error message seen above in the screenshot, but preceded by this:

Can't locate Data/Dumper.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Users/cyanofsky/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/gdata/perl C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/lib .) at C:/Users/cyanofsky/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/gdata/perl/module_tools.pl line 11.

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Users/cyanofsky/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/gdata/perl/module_tools.pl line 11.

Compilation failed in require at C:/Users/cyanofsky/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/gdata/perl/supportedFormats.pl line 9.

running 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.1\bin\x64\Rterm.exe --slave --no-restore --no-save --no-restore --file=C:/Program Files (x86)/LyX 2.0/Resources/scripts/lyxknitr.R --args C:/Users/cyanofsky/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp8008/lyx_tmpbuf3/xxxxxxxxx.Rnw C:/Users/cyanofsky/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp8008/lyx_tmpbuf3/xxxxxxxx.tex ISO-8859-15'

---

ETA: A search for Data/Dumper pulled up this:

http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=189

I verified that my install of Perl64 has the Data module; it's in C:\Perl64\lib. So this is a case where some path variable somewhere is misconfigured. It's not LyX's path prefix variable; no, no, that would be too easy.

---

Per Yihui's answer:

From within the GUI (in this case, RStudio):

```
> strsplit(Sys.getenv('PATH'), ';')
[[1]]
 [1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.1\\bin\\x64"                        
 [2] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.1\\bin\\x64"                        
 [3] "C:\\Perl64\\site\\bin"                                          
 [4] "C:\\Perl64\\bin"                                                
 [5] "c:\\Rtools\\bin"                                                
 [6] "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin"                                     
 [7] "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86_64"                  
 [8] "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86"                     
 [9] "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\"                  
[10] "c:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\"                        
[11] "C:\\Windows\\system32"                                          
[12] "C:\\Windows"                                                    
[13] "C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem"                                    
[14] "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\"               
[15] "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\ATI Technologies\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static"
[16] ""                                                               
[17] "C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\"                          
[18] "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\"       
[19] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\OpenCL SDK\\3.0\\bin\\x86"      
[20] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\OpenCL SDK\\3.0\\bin\\x64"      
[21] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\"             

> Sys.which('perl')
                       perl 
"C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe"
```

Here's from within the call to Rscript:

```
> load("~/lyxknitrpaths.RData")
> syspath
[[1]]
 [1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.1\\bin\\x644"                       
 [2] "LyXDir\\bin"                                                    
 [3] "$LyXDir\\Python"                                                
 [4] "$LyXDir\\Python\\Lib"                                           
 [5] "$LyXDir\\imagemagick"                                           
 [6] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin"               
 [7] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LyX 2.0\\ghostscript\\bin"             
 [8] "C:\\Perl64\\lib"                                                
 [9] "C:\\Perl64"                                                     
[10] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LyX 2.0\\\\Python"                     
[11] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LyX 2.0\\\\Python\\Lib"                
[12] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LyX 2.0\\\\imagemagick"                
[13] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LyX 2.0\\\\bin"                        
[14] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LyX 2.0\\bin\\"                        
[15] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.1\\bin\\x64"                        
[16] "C:\\Perl64\\site\\bin"                                          
[17] "C:\\Perl64\\bin"                                                
[18] "c:\\Rtools\\bin"                                                
[19] "c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin"                                     
[20] "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86_64"                  
[21] "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86"                     
[22] "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\"                  
[23] "c:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\"                        
[24] "C:\\Windows\\System32"                                          
[25] "C:\\Windows"                                                    
[26] "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem"                                    
[27] "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\"               
[28] "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\ATI Technologies\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static"
[29] "C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\"                          
[30] "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\"       
[31] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\OpenCL SDK\\3.0\\bin\\x86"      
[32] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\OpenCL SDK\\3.0\\bin\\x64"      
[33] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\"             

> perlpath
                                             perl 
"C:\\PROGRA~2\\MIKTEX~1.9\\miktex\\bin\\perl.exe"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like two instances of Perl clashed somehow in your `PATH`. Please post the output of the code below

```
strsplit(Sys.getenv('PATH'), ';')
Sys.which('perl')
```

from both LyX/knitr and plain R. (Feel free to replace anything concerning privacy such as your user name with `foobar`)

Comment: Info above as per your request. Accounting for character case, there's nothing on the GUI path that isn't also on the lyxknitr.R path.

Comment: Ah, got it. I altered lyxknitr.R to ensure that MikTex was taken off the PATH; now, gdata finds the right instance of perl.

Comment: @Cyan That solves the problem, but is probably not the ideal way to go. What I would prefer is to edit `Tools-->Preferences-->Paths-->PATH prefix`, and make sure the path to MikTeX is not included there, since it is already in your system's `PATH`, and it causes its `perl` to have precedence over your own Perl.

Comment: So I gave that a try, and it doesn't resolve the problem -- I think the order of the elements on the system path is the culprit here.

Comment: @Cyan Exactly, the order of PATH elements is the root of the problem. Well, I'm not under Windows at the moment, so I cannot verify it. Accordingly to your attempt, it might be that LyX forcibly adds the path of MikTeX to the PATH.